# Wordpress WP Clone plugin is resetting my site

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site I need to clone for testing purposes. I used Open-Shift to host the scratch site that I will be working on. As for cloning, I am using the WP Clone plugin. When I create a backup file on the real site, it works, and then I paste the URL on the restore for the scratch site. When I go to my scratch site however, none of the content is their, and I have to re-setup Wordpress. Is there another, better, more reliable way to clone a Wordpress site, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have used WP-Clone quite a bit, and unfortunately in this scenario, it is the most solid plugin I have found.  If you want to go the same route you have been (ie: use a plugin)...you have multiple options.  You could check out:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

And if you don't mind a little bit of complexity - the most comprehensive solution is probably more like:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

I hope that helps.  Sometimes those types of plugins can be a little buggy - and it is still a good idea to scan your database to make sure the information was transferred correctly.

Also, have you checked your wp-config file to make sure it is pointing at the correct database on the new site?  Sometimes that requires a manual change, as they differ.

Cheers.